# are the values of pointers provided by __FILE__ and __FUNCTION__ unchanging?

Tags: gcc

From the simple demo below, the output shows the string pointers **FILE** and **FUNCTION** are unchanging between invocations. (i.e. the addresses of the strings remains constant) Is this always true? (compiled for linux g++ and cross-compiled for windows with mingw)

```
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0048 flf.c:19:int main(int, char**)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0033 flf.c:11:int first_thing(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0004 flf.c:5:int second_function(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0004 flf.c:5:int second_function(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0033 flf.c:11:int first_thing(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0004 flf.c:5:int second_function(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0004 flf.c:5:int second_function(int)
0x556c923b001d 0x556c923b0004 flf.c:5:int second_function(int)
```

I want to know if I can safely store these pointers in my own structures for the life of my program and be sure that they are always valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int second_function(int y)
{
    printf("%p %p %s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return 0;
}

int first_thing(int x)
{
    printf("%p %p %s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    second_function(1);
    second_function(2);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%p %p %s:%d:%s\n", __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    first_thing(3);
    first_thing(4);
    second_function(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `between invocations` what is an "invocation"?

Comment: Hi, I trying to avoid using the word "call"  as it might be a function or a macro,

Answer (score 0):

> Is this always true?

Yes.

> if I can safely store these pointers in my own structures for the life of my program and be sure that they are always valid.

Yes.

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a gcc extension. Use `__func__` to be portable instead.